# Definite integral of a power times a cosine

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function

The following integral appears in Gradshteyn & Rhyzik, page 421 3.769
$$\int_0^{\infty } x^{\mu -1}
   \cos (a x) \,
   dx=\frac{\Gamma (\mu ) \cos
   \left(\frac{\mu  \pi
   }{2}\right)}{a^{\mu }}$$
(*a*>0, $0<\Re(\mu )<1$)

I am looking for a derivation

Comment: You misspell his name. He is Ryzhik and his address according to Google, is  ryzhik@math.stanford.edu.

Comment: You can use Ramanujan's Master Theorem if you are familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above,the integral in question is obtained trivially from Ramanujan's Master Theorem. Another approach is to use contour integration with *f*(*z*)=$z^{\mu -1} e^{i a z}$ where the contour consists of the two circular arcs $C_{\epsilon }$ and $C_R$ in the first quadrant along with the segements from ($\epsilon$,0) to (*R*,0) and (0,$\epsilon$) to (0,*R*). The intergral along $C_{\epsilon }$ approaches zero as $\epsilon \to 0$ and the integral along $C_R$ approaches zero as $R\to \infty$. The intgral along the segment of the real axis becomes $\int_0^{\infty } x^{\mu -1}
   e^{i x} \, dx$ while he intgral along the segment of the imaginary axis assumes the form $e^{\frac{i \pi  \mu }{2}}
   \Gamma (\mu )$. Taking the real parts of both expressions yields the required integral.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually the mentioned theorem holds true for all $\Re(\mu)>0$. Well there are a couple of methods using complex Analysis but there is also an approach using simple real analysis.
Start with the integral definition of gamma function,
$$\Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt, \Re(s)>0$$
Substitute, $t=pu^{n} \implies dt=pnu^{n-1}du$
$$\Gamma(s)=np^{s} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{ns-1} e^{-pu^{n}}du$$
Divide by $np^{s}$ on both sides of equation,
$$\frac{\Gamma(s)}{np^{s}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{ns-1}e^{-pu^{n}} du \rightarrow (1)$$
Now here's the trick. Let $p$ be a complex number. It sounds weird , as we did everything under assumption that $p$  was real. But you can actually verify it to be true by taking some examples.
Now let, $p=a+ib=|p|e^{i\alpha}$
Similar to $(1)$ consider the complex conjugate of $p$. And rewrite the integral,
$$\frac{\Gamma(s)}{n(\bar{p})^{s}} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{ns-1}e^{-\bar{p}u^{n}}du \rightarrow (2)$$
Add $(1),(2)$ and use $p=a+ib=|p|e^{i\alpha}$.
$$\frac{\Gamma(s)e^{-is\alpha}}{n|p|^{s}}+\frac{\Gamma(s)e^{is\alpha}}{n|p|^{s}}=\int_{0}^{\infty} u^{ns-1}e^{-au^{n}}(e^{ibu^{n}}+e^{-ibu^{n}})du$$
By using the Euler's formula,
$$\frac{\Gamma(s)\cos(s\alpha)}{n|p|^{s}} =\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{ns-1}e^{-at^{n}}\cos(bu^{n})du$$
This result is powerful than expected. You can prove stuff like Dirichlet integral, Fresnel integral and others which require complex Analysis using this simple integral.
$$\frac{\Gamma(s)\cos(s\alpha)}{n|p|^{s}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{ns-1}e^{-au^{n}}\cos(bu^{n})du$$
Adjust the values of $p,n$ as required. In this case, set $a=0, p=ib, n=1$. Since real part is $0$, argument equals $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Putting all the values In the integral above
$$\frac{\Gamma(s)\cos(s\frac{\pi}{2})}{b^{s})} =\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{s-1}\cos(bu) du$$
Since the integral definition of gamma function we considered converges for all $\Re(s) \gt 1$, we have that
$$\frac{\Gamma(s)\cos(s\frac{\pi}{2})}{b^{s}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{s-1}\cos(bu) du$$
For all $\Re(s)>0$.

The integral I derived is called as Euler integral. I found it [here](https://youtu.be/VF7ud3Al6d8)

Comment: The intrgral does not converge for all  for which ℜ()>0. Clearly for a=1 and =2 the integral is divergent. When we make the substitution =p u^n  (assuming n>0) there is the problem of finding the value of u corresponding to =∞. If  p>0, then yes,  u=∞. If say p=i, then u=i ∞. Can you cite a publication where this formal step is justified ?